Apache2 default won't load on other device

Issue: Accessing Apache2 on VMware Workstation from a Different System
Steps I've Taken:

Started Apache2 on the VM:
sudo su
service apache2 start


Verified Apache2 is Running:

When I open the page with the VM's IP address on the VM itself, it loads correctly.


Problem:

When I try to access the page from a Windows system on the same network, it doesn't work.


Troubleshooting Attempted:
service httpd status


Result: unit httpd.service could not be found



Network Configuration:

I am using a bridged connection in VMware.

Additional Information:

The Windows system and the VM are on the same network.
I expected the page to load when accessed from the Windows system using the VM's IP address.

Request for Help:

How can I access the Apache2 server running on my VM from a different system on the same network?
Are there additional configurations or steps I need to take?


This should make it easier for others to understand your problem and offer assistance.

"When I open the page with the VM's IP address on the VM itself, it loads correctly." Sounds like there could be a firewall blocking the connection.
